# Calling javascript function with undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in javascript :

```
function test(a, b, c) {
    if(typeof b == "undefined")
      //do something 
    //function code
}
```

Now i want to call this function in such a way so that `typeof b remains undefined` and `a & c containes` value (**without reordering `a`, `b` & `c`**), like

```
test("value for a",  what i can pass here so that b type will be undefined, "value for c")
```

Comment: Create a variable without value and use it or maybe even a non existing variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply pass `undefined` (without quotes):

```
test("value for a", undefined, "value for c");
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on undefined for control flow (especially not for arguments). The value could be legit or it could be masking an error. Yes it's what OP is asking for but guiding him in a more productive direction want harm :)

Answer (score 4):

Any variable (that's undefined).

```
var undefinedVar;
test("value for a", undefinedVar, "value for b");
```

Comment: Why not just use `undefined`? No sane person will ever redefine it and modern engines don't allow that anyway.

Comment: Yeah could do. There's more than one way of skinning a cat though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Minor correction: modern engines don’t allow redefining the *global* `undefined`. `(function() { var undefined = 42; }());` is still allowed by the spec, and would work. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest another approach if you know that you either pass a,b and c or you pass a and c. Then do as follows

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  if (arguments.length < 3){
      c = b;
      b = arguments[2]; //undefined
      //do want ever you would do if b is undefined
  }
}
```

In this case if you by mistake pass an undefined for b it's easier to spot because it's not interpreted as *"undefined actually doesn't mean undefined but is a flag telling me to do something different"*  it's usually more robust to test the arguments length than to rely on the value of the parameters especially if that value can also be the result of an error (Ie.  if the value is undefined)

Comment: agree, `typeof x == "undefined"` is just horrible in general as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator:

```
test('value for a', void 0, 'value for c');
```

`void` operator evaluates the `expression` and returns `undefined`.